# How to pull relevant information from multiple repositories?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web

**Problem Statement:**

Information is spanned across multiple repositories - SAP, DB etc. Now when I search to a particular thing, I want to pull the relevant data from all the repositories. (For time being, Assume that I am able to pull the data from all these repositories in a huge XML format.)

How to add meaning to my search?

I am looking for a java based solution.

Will Jena/Semantic-Web helps me? Can I define the relationships in RDFs?

With the very little knowledge I have about Semantic Web, I am trying to understand whether it addresses my problem. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "add meaning to my search"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've asked a collection of questions here (which, as an aside, isn't really best practice for StackOverflow), but I think the key question you're asking is:

> How to add meaning to my search?

This really depends on having a clear understanding of the business value or user experience you are trying to deliver. "Meaning" is an imprecise term -- I think you'll have a much easier time analyzing which technologies you need if you can be much more precise about categories of questions you want your users to be able to ask, and what kinds of answers they will find useful.

With that caveat in mind, my general answer to your general question would be that, in order to integrate information from disparate, heterogeneous information sources, you need to be able to relate them together conceptually *in terms that your users will understand*. So, not just a low-level "this db field maps to that XML element", but, for example, "this dataset records customer interactions with the sales team, these are stats for the production line throughput, and they are related via the orders in the order queue". That's a bit vague, but it's a made-up example to give a flavour of the kind of thing I mean. The way, then, to relate CRM information to manufacturing statistics is to have some *collection of concepts* that you can relate everything to. In the semantic web world, we call this an *ontology*. Designing an ontology to cover your entire business is likely to be hard, but you can, loosely speaking, apply agile techniques to develop your understanding and your ontological model incrementally.

Once you have an ontology, you can use libraries such as Jena to help you with the nuts-and-bolts of pulling information from the disparate sources and storing them in a form that you can relate to your ontology. An advantage of making your ontology explicit, using a language such as RDFS, or better still, OWL, is that you can use automated reasoning tools to draw new conclusions from your data automatically, or else to represent some of your data mappings as rules. Some people find rules to be a more abstract and understandable notation.

There are many ways to solve the problem you're describing, and Jena won't give you solution *per se*. I think that having a suitable ontology will be pretty essential for what I understand of your problem. How complex that ontology needs to be will be driven by the complexity of the data and the user needs, which will depend on having a clearer business-level understanding of the problem. Once you have that, then selecting the right RDF/OWL tools will be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You may use approach such as ISO 15926. In this standart you have abstract model (201 entities), and have RDL (Reference Data Library) for specific field of knowledge.
In order to use one global query to all repository, you may use mapping between different app, and store mapping equivalence in RDF. In this way you need use facade  for each app.

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches:

- Pull data, index it (Lucene?) and search in your "copy" using your custom index. I would avoid this if possible, as the moving large amount of data is usually bad idea.
- Move some agents as close to the data sources as possible, run queries locally (close to SAP, DB, etc.) and transfer only the portion of a result that you really need.

Consider looking at integration frameworks as Apache Camel or Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

If there is indeed some general conceptual model which allows you to map all the data to a coherent ontology, you could follow the route Ian Dickinson recommends. If you're using SAP, I'm guessing you're talking about large amounts of data, and a moderately complex business domain. Such a project would be a major undertaking - and the technical element is only the start.

I worked on such a project long before the semantic web was born, and it was a huge, complex beast of a project. The problem wasn't so much technical, it was that the business specialists had conflicting ideas about the meaning of words, the relationships between business concepts ("all employees must belong to a single department. Oh, except Fred, who moonlights for Finance"), and found it hard to work with the abstractions we techies loved to use.

The alternative is based on "search" - find a way to represent your data in some minimal structure, use Lucene (or similar) to build an index, and allow users to navigate through that mechanism. Of course, that may mean building a fairly complex web application, but I think most people are used to Google to find what they want...